# using argmax in maximum a posteriori estimation from max likelihood estimation

Tags: bayesian, notation

I was going through maximum a posteriori estimation and could not understand, why **argmax** is used for first term in image shown below but missing from second term. Shouldn't we have used **argmax** for both of them? If not what is the reasoning behind this.
[image: MAP estimation steps]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading the notation.

$$
\underset{\theta}{\operatorname{arg\,max}} \log P(X|\theta) + \log P(\theta) = \underset{\theta}{\operatorname{arg\,max}} \Big( \log P(X|\theta) + \log P(\theta) \Big)
$$

Comment: Thanks, now you cleared my confusion. So I can add bracket before all equation down the line and before summation, without changing the meaning. Obviously p(theta) is constant, so need of argmax.